# Sendmail form feedback, Variables declaration?

Tags: php, forms, email, feedback

Im am using this script
http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_form_to_email.cfm

It works good as default.

but i have added a few extra variables likes :

```
/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$namn = $_REQUEST['namn'] ;
$telefonnummer = $_REQUEST['telefonnummer'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;
```

My problem is I cant manage to get them show up in the email that gets sent.

I have tried include them like this:

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
  $namn, $email, $telefonnummer, $comments, "From: $email_address" );
```

and this:

```
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
  $email, ;)
  $telefonnummer, :)
```

its not working out,  Do you have any idea what i do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code don't match `mail()` definition: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You should have:

```
mail( $webmaster_email, "Feedback Form Results", "$namn, $email, $telefonnummer, $comments", "From: $email_address" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function , it accepts four parameters

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

so you should change your code so that it looks something like this considering you did everything all right in form where you added these new fields

```
$message=$namn.','. $email.','. $telefonnummer.','. $comments;
mail( $webmaster_email, "Feedback Form Results",  $message, "From: {$email_address}" );
```

Also you might need some additional info in your header (forth parameter) so that your message displays correctly in case it has some html inside, take a look at this example from php.net

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

 // Mail it
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look at [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php). You have way to many parameters.

Basic usage is: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers);`

Try:

```
/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$namn = $_REQUEST['namn'] ;
$telefonnummer = $_REQUEST['telefonnummer'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

$message = 'namn: ' . $namn . ' telefonnummer: ' . $telefonnummer . ' email_address: ' . $email_address . ' comments: ' . $comments;

mail($webmaster_email, "Feedback Form Results", $message, "From: $email_address");
```